# Select from two dates, automatically displaying consecutive rows data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I expect to select from two date, automatically displaying consecutive time rows data.

e.g:

```
Select * 
from somefunction('2013/5','2019/3');
```

Expected result:

```
Year | Month
-----+------
2013 |  5
2013 |  6
..   | ..
2013 | 12
..   | ..
..   | ..
2019 |  1
2019 |  2
2019 |  3
```

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/get-months-name-between-date-ranges-with-sql-query/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem, and the solution is provided here .

> ```
> declare @dStart datetime = '2013/05/01'
> ,@dEnd datetime = '2019/03/31';
>
> SELECT year(Dateadd(month,number,@dStart)) as year,month(Dateadd(month,number,@dStart)) as month
> FROM master..spt_values
> WHERE 
>     type = 'P'
>     AND number <= DATEDIFF(month, @dStart, @dEnd)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> year | month
> ---: | ----:
> 2013 |     5
> 2013 |     6
> 2013 |     7
> 2013 |     8
> 2013 |     9
> 2013 |    10
> 2013 |    11
> 2013 |    12
> 2014 |     1
> 2014 |     2
> 2014 |     3
> 2014 |     4
> 2014 |     5
> 2014 |     6
> 2014 |     7
> 2014 |     8
> 2014 |     9
> 2014 |    10
> 2014 |    11
> 2014 |    12
> 2015 |     1
> 2015 |     2
> 2015 |     3
> 2015 |     4
> 2015 |     5
> 2015 |     6
> 2015 |     7
> 2015 |     8
> 2015 |     9
> 2015 |    10
> 2015 |    11
> 2015 |    12
> 2016 |     1
> 2016 |     2
> 2016 |     3
> 2016 |     4
> 2016 |     5
> 2016 |     6
> 2016 |     7
> 2016 |     8
> 2016 |     9
> 2016 |    10
> 2016 |    11
> 2016 |    12
> 2017 |     1
> 2017 |     2
> 2017 |     3
> 2017 |     4
> 2017 |     5
> 2017 |     6
> 2017 |     7
> 2017 |     8
> 2017 |     9
> 2017 |    10
> 2017 |    11
> 2017 |    12
> 2018 |     1
> 2018 |     2
> 2018 |     3
> 2018 |     4
> 2018 |     5
> 2018 |     6
> 2018 |     7
> 2018 |     8
> 2018 |     9
> 2018 |    10
> 2018 |    11
> 2018 |    12
> 2019 |     1
> 2019 |     2
> 2019 |     3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f579a17b1bbd6fbdee8cc5c192f6a976)*